# More elements to be toggled, but I only want to toggle the one i clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, toggle

When I now click on a `table a` that I want to toggle the `.info` inside the same div, it toggles the `.info` in the other divs too. Can somebody please help me?

```js
function info() {
  $('.table a').click(function() {
    $('.info').toggle();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="table">
    <a class="table-row" title="mehr &darr;">
      <div class="table-cell l">
        19:30
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        Eröffnung + <b>Nwabis Plaatjie</b>: 3 Years, a month and 7 days
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell r">
        Experimentiertheater
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <h1>test</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="table">
    <a class="table-row" title="mehr &darr;">
      <div class="table-cell l">
        19:30
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        Eröffnung + <b>Nwabis Plaatjie</b>: 3 Years, a month and 7 days
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell r">
        Experimentiertheater
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <h1>test</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting all the `.info` elements before calling `toggle()`. Instead, you need to find the one relevant to the clicked `a`. To do that you can use the `this` keyword within the click handler and traverse the DOM, retrieving the parent `.table`, then the next sibling `.info`. Try this:

```js
function info() {
  $('.table a').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.table').next('.info').toggle();
  });
}

info();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="table">
    <a class="table-row" title="mehr &darr;">
      <div class="table-cell l">
        19:30
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        Eröffnung + <b>Nwabis Plaatjie</b>: 3 Years, a month and 7 days
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell r">
        Experimentiertheater
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <h1>test</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="table">
    <a class="table-row" title="mehr &darr;">
      <div class="table-cell l">
        19:30
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        Eröffnung + <b>Nwabis Plaatjie</b>: 3 Years, a month and 7 days
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell r">
        Experimentiertheater
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <h1>test</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.table a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.table').next('.info').toggle();
});
```

```css
.info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="table">
        <a class="table-row" title="mehr &darr;">
            <div class="table-cell l">
                19:30
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell">
                Eröffnung + <b>Nwabis Plaatjie</b>: 3 Years, a month and 7 days
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell r">
                Experimentiertheater
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="table">
        <a class="table-row" title="mehr &darr;">
            <div class="table-cell l">
                19:30
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell">
                Eröffnung + <b>Nwabis Plaatjie</b>: 3 Years, a month and 7 days
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell r">
                Experimentiertheater
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A description of the problem/solution would help educate the OP for future cases